# ¿Cómo pasar parámetros a un store procedure de PostgreSQL en C#

Tags: c#, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, ado.net

Necesito pasar parámetros en C# para PostgreSQL:

```
public static IEnumerable<Articulo> SelectListFunc(UniversalExtend filter)
    {
        using (var cn = new NpgsqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ToString()))
        {
            cn.Open();
            using (var cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "usp_selectlist";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idarticulo", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Id)
                    ? (object)DBNull.Value
                    : $"%{filter.Id}%");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@descripcion", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Descripcion)
                    ? (object)DBNull.Value
                    : $"%{filter.Descripcion}%");

                var _articulo = new List<Articulo>();
                using (NpgsqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        var a = new Articulo()
                        {
                            IdArticulo = Convert.ToString(reader["idarticulo"]),
                            Descripcion = Convert.ToString(reader["descripcion"])
                        };
                        _articulo.Add(a);
                    }
                }
                return _articulo.ToList();
            }   
        }
    }
```

Pero obtengo el error siguiente:

> Error : No existe la función usp_selectlist(idarticulo := character
>   varying, descripcion := character varying)

Comment: Tengo entendido que en `C#` se concatena con el *operador* `+` ¿por qué estás intentandolo con ese cáracter?

Comment: @Naos por el titulo.

Comment: ¿No puedes convertir los párametros a un `string` y luego concatenarlos como tal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para contestar esta pregunta, voy a asumir que definistes la función `usp_selectlist` de la manera como te lo recomendé en tu otra pregunta: [Como crear un store procedure en PosgreSQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/43626/como-crear-un-store-procedure-en-posgresql/). Esto incluye el ajuste en cuanto a mover el `%` dentro de la función, en vez de pasarlo como parámetro.

O sea, usando una función definido de esta forma:

```sql
create function usp_selectlist(p_IdArticulo varchar, p_Descripcion varchar)
returns table(IdArticulo varchar,
              Descripcion varchar)
as $$
  select IdArticulo, Descripcion
    from tblarticulos
   where (p_IdArticulo is null or IdArticulo ilike '%' || p_IdArticulo || '%')
     and (p_Descripcion is null or Descripcion ilike '%' || p_Descripcion || '%');
$$ language sql;
```

**Usando `CommandType.Text`**

La primera opción es ejecutar la función como si fuera una consulta SQL normal usando `CommandType.Text`:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select * from usp_selectlist(@idarticulo, @descripcion)";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(
    "@idarticulo",
    NpgsqlDbType.Varchar,
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Id)
        ? (object)DBNull.Value
        : filter.Id);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(
    "@descripcion",
    NpgsqlDbType.Varchar,
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Descripcion)
        ? (object)DBNull.Value
        : filter.Descripcion);
```

Usando esta opción, no tienes que preocuparte de los nombres de los parámetros definidos en la función (`p_IdArticulo`, `p_Descripcion`). Puedes escoger los nombres que quieras (`@idarticulo`, `@descripcion`). Lo importante es que especifiques el tipo correcto al pasar los parámetros (`NpgsqlDbType.Varchar`).

Adicionalmente, tienes la flexibilidad de poder enriquecer la llamada a la función, tal vez agregándole un `ORDER BY`, o lo que quieras, como si fuera una consulta SQL normal. No necesitas hacerlo, pero la opción está allí.

**Usando `CommandType.StoredProcedure`**

Esta opción se parece más a la forma como se ejecutan los stored procedures con otras bases de datos usando `CommandType.StoredProcedure`:

```
cmd.CommandText = "usp_selectlist";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

// ¡ojo! "parameterName" debe ser igual al parámetro de la función, pero en minúsculas.
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(
    "p_idarticulo",
    NpgsqlDbType.Varchar,
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Id)
        ? (object)DBNull.Value
        : filter.Id);

// ¡ojo! "parameterName" debe ser igual al parámetro de la función, pero en minúsculas.
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(
    "p_descripcion",
    NpgsqlDbType.Varchar,
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Descripcion)
        ? (object)DBNull.Value
        : filter.Descripcion);
```

Contrario a la opción anterior, aquí debes tener mucho cuidado de especificar los nombres de los parámetros de forma que sean idénticos a los nombres de los parámetros en la definición de la función. Es más, si los parámetros en la función fueron definidos con una mezcla de mayúsculas y minúsculas, como lo hize yo en mi ejemplo (`p_IdArticulo`, `p_Descripcion`), entonces debes usar los nombres equivalentes, pero usando solo minúsculas (`p_idarticulo`, `p_descripcion`).

Si no especificas bien los nombres de los parámetros, entonces recibes el error:

> No existe la función usp_selectlist(idarticulo := character varying, descripcion := character varying)

Comment: Buena la respuesta **sstan**