# ¿Cómo crear un store procedure en PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Estoy trabajando con PostgreSQL y deseo crear esta consulta en un Store Procedure de PostgreSQL. Pero tratando la sintaxis como tal, me refiero a sintaxis PostgreSQL.

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT IdArticulo, Descripcion FROM tblarticulos" +
                " WHERE (@IdArticulo IS NULL OR IdArticulo ILIKE @IdArticulo)" +
                " AND (@Descripcion IS NULL OR Descripcion ILIKE @Descripcion)";
```

Comment: Hola Pedro, solo para no contestar en la dirección equivocada.. ¿cual es la motivación tras el querer convertir la consulta a un SP?

Comment: @sstan me pidieron hacer esa búsqueda LIKE y la hice con una consulta, pero me pidieron hacerla con un store procedure de postgresql, pero dije que no era necesario para un simple like. aunque cambie la técnica de buscar productos en una tabla que tiene 23, 581 registros a mi parecer no es mucho pero con la técnica de búsqueda que uso desde la aplicación bajo notablemente pero aún así me pidieron que use un store(funcion) de postgresql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En PostgreSQL, no existen los stored procedures como tal. Lo mas cercano a un stored procedure son las funciones.

En mi opinión, la forma mas simple de encapsular una consulta dentro de lo que se *parece* a un stored procedure en PostgreSQL, es usando un *table function*. O sea, una función que puedes manejar como si fuera una tabla.

Es mas, como no tienes necesidad de ningún tipo de lógica fuera de la consulta en sí, ni siquiera necesitas usar el lenguage plpgsql para definir la función. Lo mas sencillo es usar el lenguaje SQL directamente, cosa que PostgreSQL maneja muy bien al definir una función.

*(Nota: después de pensarlo con mas calma, me parece que en efecto tiene mas sentido de guardar los `%` directamente en la consulta, en vez de pasarlos en el valor de los parámetros, contrario a lo que pensaba antes. Las funciones que muestro aquí reflejan ese cambio.)*

**Función usando lenguaje `SQL`**

```
create function usp_selectlist(p_IdArticulo varchar, p_Descripcion varchar)
returns table(IdArticulo varchar,
              Descripcion varchar)
as $$
  select IdArticulo, Descripcion
    from tblarticulos
   where (p_IdArticulo is null or IdArticulo ilike '%' || p_IdArticulo || '%')
     and (p_Descripcion is null or Descripcion ilike '%' || p_Descripcion || '%');
$$ language sql;
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/TROX35033)</kbd>

**Función usando lenguage `PLpgSQL`**

```
create function usp_selectlist(p_IdArticulo varchar, p_Descripcion varchar)
returns table(IdArticulo varchar,
              Descripcion varchar)
as $$
begin
  return query
  select t.IdArticulo, t.Descripcion
    from tblarticulos t
   where (p_IdArticulo is null or t.IdArticulo ilike '%' || p_IdArticulo || '%')
     and (p_Descripcion is null or t.Descripcion ilike '%' || p_Descripcion || '%');
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/OBJZ90093)</kbd>

Ambas opciones son equivalentes. Solo que, personalmente optaría por la primera opción, simplemente porque no hay necesidad de la segunda.

Para usar la función, simplemente la llamas como si tratara de una tabla con parámetros.

Ejemplo:

```
select *
  from usp_selectlist('456', null);

select *
  from usp_selectlist(null, 'pedro');
```

**Opción usando cursores**

Otra opción es definir una función que devuelva un cursor. No voy a incluir esa opción aquí, porque no creo que sea ventajoso. Mas bien, tiene una limitación bien molestosa: solo se puede usar si abres una transacción antes de ejecutar la función.

**Cómo llamar la función desde C# usando ADO.NET.**

Como veo que abristes una pregunta separada para el aspecto de la llamada desde C#, voy a agregar este detalle bajo la otra pregunta que hicistes: [Como pasar parámetros a un store procedure de PosgreSQL en C#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/43615/como-pasar-par%C3%A1metros-a-un-store-procedure-de-posgresql-en-c).

Comment: me sale el siguiente error cuando ejecuto la primera opción(sql) en el servidor. ERROR:  no existe la columna «p_idarticulo»
LINE 7:    where (p_IdArticulo is null or IdArticulo ilike '%' || p_...

Comment: Funciono haciendo esta modificación. `select IdArticulo, Descripcion
    from tblarticulos
   where ($1 is null or IdArticulo ilike '%' || $1 || '%')
     and ($2 is null or Descripcion ilike '%' || $2 || '%');`, revisala.

Comment: A saber por qué te dio ese error. Me alegra que te funcione, pero si te interesa tratar de entender el error, puedes tratar de comparar con el enlace `Demo`, donde puedes ver que funciona bien, y ver si hay alguna diferencia con lo que tenías.

Comment: cuando corro la query en la consola del PostgreSQL no interpreta  p_IdArticulo como parámetro. Claro que en la demo si funciona de maravilla.